# Terminal Velocity

Tags: gravity, velocity, friction

Let Suppose a bullet of 2 gram is falling with the speed of 200km/h.
Now how can we know the time after which it gains it terminal velocity.

Also when it gain its terminal velocity the force of friction and gravity will becomes equal and it stop accelarating do at this point the force of friction acting on it becomes constant or it go on increasing and also decrease the velocity of object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not actually friction, it's the *drag force*, also called air resistance. Technically, they're different (even though people do sometimes say "air friction"). The drag force depends on the object's speed, shape, and size, as well as the density of the air, but in the ideal case you can assume that the object's shape and size and the density are constant.

In that case, when an object is falling at terminal velocity, the forces on it balance out, which means it has zero acceleration - in other words, its velocity doesn't change. And if the velocity doesn't change, then the drag force, which depends on velocity, won't change either. So the object is "stuck" in a steady state in which the drag force on it will remain constant as it falls.

In practice, though, an object never actually reaches terminal velocity unless it starts at terminal velocity. As it gets closer and closer to terminal velocity, the drag force on it gets closer and closer to exactly balancing out the gravitational force, which means that the net force on it, and thus its acceleration, becomes less and less. Basically, as the object gets closer to terminal velocity, the rate at which it continues to approach terminal velocity gets slower. It'll get continually closer to terminal velocity as time goes on, but it never quite reaches it.

Last year I wrote a [blog post](http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2010/04/calculating-terminal-speed.html) about this issue which discusses it using the actual math. It might be of interest to you.

Comment: @David - I think that the difficulty here is to explain (or show) why there is no overshoot of the velocity when approaching the Vt. Since this is a nonlinear equation, one needs to actually prove that the convergence is exponential (or similar). I think your blog post does it well.

Comment: @ysap: fair enough; it seemed to me based on the style of the question that the OP might not want to get into the full mathematical detail, so I opted for a less technical explanation (with a link to more mathematical detail for anyone interested, of course).

Comment: @ysap -- As long as you know the equation is second-order -- that is, that the force doesn't depend on higher-order derivatives than the acceleration -- there can't be any overshoot. By definition, the terminal velocity is the velocity such that $a=0$. So if at any point the velocity reaches that terminal velocity, then the acceleration at that moment will be zero, and the unique solution to the differential equation from then on will be $v=$ constant. Heuristically, if there were overshoot, it would mean that there was a moment when $v$ is the terminal velocity but $a>0$, which is impossible.

Comment: will you please explain why an object never actually reaches terminal velocity unless it starts at terminal velocity.

Comment: Zain: Under the constant atmosphere simplification, you need some excess of graviational force versus drag in order for the velocity to increase. As the velocity approaches terminal velocity the net acceleration approaches zero, so it takes an infinire amount of time to reach that state. In the real world, an object falling from a great height will reflect the terminal velocity of the less dense air some height above its current height, and could in fact exceed the locally defined terminal velocity.

Comment: @Ted Bunn - I totally agree with you on the heuristics. It makes a compete sense to say that v cannot be greater than vt. However, I don't agree that the term "Terminal Velocity" implies that it is the max speed. It merely means the speed at steady state. Since we deal with nonlinear diff. eqn. here, it is not completely safe to assume anything. With a slightly different eqn., it can converge harmonically (or not...). Again - I have no problem with the logic, I just pointed out a case where we should be cautious.

Comment: @Zain - to add to @OmegaCentauri's comment, from the mathematical standpoint, the motion is described by an exponential function (you can see the solution in David's blog post). The nature of this function is that it *never* reaches the final (asymptotic) value, no matter what the initial value is, except when you start at the final value. Hence, the velocity velocity never reaches the terminal velocity.

Comment: @ysap -- I don't think I understand your objection. My argument shows that, if you start below the terminal speed, you can never exceed it. (Because if you did, you'd have to pass through the terminal speed, but if you pass through it you'd stay there.) I don't understand what stronger statement you're interested in proving.

Comment: @Zain -- The same sort of argument I was giving earlier also explain why you can never reach terminal speed in finite time (unless you started there). Suppose that $v=v_T$, the terminal speed, at some moment $t_0$. Then, by the uniqueness of solutions to differential equations, we can conclude that $v(t)=v_T$ at all future times, but also at all *past* times. So if you weren't at $v_T$ at some moment before $t_0$, you can't be at $v_T$ at $t_0$. This result doesn't depend on any particular form for the drag force, as long as it involves no higher-order derivatives beyond $a$.

Comment: @TedBunn - OK, I think we are wasting energy here arguing on something we all basically agree. I tried to pointed out that when dealing with diff. eqn., especially nonlinear and/or high-order, sometimes plain logic may be misleading, and a more elaborated math proof has to be given. Now, to your last comment to *me*, saying *"Because if you did, you'd have to pass through the terminal speed, but if you pass through it you'd stay there"*, is merely repeating an argument and not explaining it. As for the last comment to Zain, I think what you wanted to say is [cont...]

Comment: [...cont] "as long as it involves no higher-order derivatives beyond the 1st". Think of a spring-mass system with a damper. Here, the eqn. does not go beyond **a**, yet the mass oscillates (if damping is low enough) while converging to the rest point. Obviously, the key here is that the eqn. is of 2nd order.

Comment: OK. I think we agree on the physics, and I probably should have been more careful in my phrasing. When I referred to derivatives beyond the second, I was thinking of the dynamical system with $x(t)$ as the unknown, but I wasn't clear about that. If (as is more natural) we think of $v$ as the unknown, then I should have said that the result works as long as the equation is first-order. My main point is that you don't need to solve the equation, or even to assume a particular form for the equation, in order to see that there are no oscillations. (Continued.)

Comment: As long as the equation to be solved is of the form $\dot v=f(v)$, there can be no oscillations. In reality the drag force is some quite complicated function of $v$ (linear at low speed, quadratic at high speed), so it's nice to know that the no-oscillation result does not depend on the specific functional form.

Comment: @TedBunn - off topic - how do you get the nice math font you have in your comments?

Comment: I'm using the standard MathJax markup, which lets you create math using TeX-like syntax. If you don't know how to use this, I think when you're creating or editing a post, there'll be a link at the right taking you to some help on this. Also, if you edit an existing post, you'll see the "source text" for any math in that post. (I don't know if you need a certain reputation level to do this, though.) For instance, to create the equation in my last comment, I wrote \dot v = f(v), with the whole thing sandwiched between two dollar signs (the dollar sign being the toggle in/out of "math mode."

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the atmosphere is constant (i.e. ignore the fact that density and pressure increase as you go downwards), then you could linearize the differential equation for the velocity versus time. [I.e. you expand the drag as a function of velocity about the terminal velocity, and keep the first order correction to drag]. If you were to do so, you will find that it exponentially approaches terminal velocity with some characteristic time.

In the more realistic case where density (and hence drag) is a function of altitude, you'll have to solve the 2nd order diffeq numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://math.kennesaw.edu/~sellerme/sfehtml/classes/math2202/fallingbodies.pdf).

d/dt(v)=g-pv

plug in the values for g and p.

for the earths surface g=-9.8 m/s^2, and p depends on altitude/air density. 
d/dt(v)=-9.8-p*v

d/dt(v)=p*(v+(-9.8/p))

1/(v+(-9.8/p),dv=p,dt

integrate both sides to get

ln(v+(-9.8/p)=p*t+C

raising both sides as exponents of e gives

v+(-9.8/p)=e^(p*t+C)=C*e^(p*t+C)

v(t)=C*e^(p*t)-(-9.8/p)

if p is known, and the velocity at time=zero is known, then the following will yield the value of C;

v(0)=C*1-(-9.8/p)

You said (I think) that v(0)=-200km/hr=-55.56m/s

so: -55.56m/s=C*1-(9.8/p)        solve for C and plugin C into: v(t)=C*e^(p*t)-(-9.8/p)

C=-55.56+(9.8/p)

v(t)=(-55.56+(9.8/p))*e^(p*t)-(-9.8/p)     this equation is (after p is plugged in) complete

tv=g/p

set the v(t) equal to tv:

g/p=(-55.56+(9.8/p))*e^(p*t)-(-9.8/p)     solve this equation for t at which tv is attained

tv=terminal velocity
v=velocity
v(t)=velocity as a function of time
g=acceleration due to gravity
p=drag coefficient
t=time
C=constant

Termial velocity is a constant unless the altitude changes enough to change the drag coefficient p. If the altitude decreases, the drag coefficient (air resistance) will likely increase and thereby slow decread the tv since tv=t/p: as p increases tv decreases.

Comment: @Joe - I'm not sure your first eqn. is correct, the drag is a function of **v^2**, not **v**. So, it should be **dv/dt = g-pv^2**.

Comment: @Joe - Also, where does the number **-55.56m/s** come from? Then, the unit for **g** is **m/s^2** and not **m/s**.

Comment: 55.56m/s=200km/hr to keep the units consistent with acceleration due to gravity (9.8m/s). it is negative because gravity is down. Drag is a function of v^2. However the change in drag with respect to time is the derivative of that. d(v^2)/dt=2*v therefore d/dt(v)=~stuff~v^(1)

Comment: @Joe - sorry, but I don't follow. 1) Going from the 1st eqn to the 2nd one in the answer, you substituted -55.56 for **g**. 2) dv/dt has units of **m/s^2**, yet you equate it with -55.56 **m/s**. 3) why do you take the derivative of **v^2** in your above comment?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could edit your answer and start at the initial (nonlinear) diff. eqn., then explain a little more the steps and substitutions you perform.

Comment: 1.) Good point on the -55.56 was intended to be -9.8 I fixed that. 2.) I equated v(0) with -55.56 not dv/dt. 3.) I took the derivative of v^2 because I missunderstood your initial comment. I did not mention the drag function in my post but rather side-stepped it through leaving the drag coefficient in the final equation.

Comment: @Joe - After the editing of the answer, there is still the problem of the 1st equation. This eqn. should be nonlinear, and look like **dv/dt = g-p*v^2**, and not as written. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You should also fix the units of **g** to **m/s^2**.

Comment: m/s^2 fixed. dv/dt=g-p*v not dv/dt=g-p*v^2 google dv/dt if you don't believe me.

Comment: 1) **a = f/m**;   2) **a = dv/dt**;   3) **Fdrag = 0.5*rho*v^2*Cd*A**   where *rho* is the density, *Cd* is the drag coefficient and *A* is the section area.

Comment: Can you explain what is **p** in your equation?

Comment: @Joe - take a look at the link provided in @David Zaslavsky's answer to this question for the full detailed equation. (I don't really need to google the terms 'cause I know the equations ;-)

Comment: p is the constant of air resistance

Comment: @Joe - ... and the air resistance is proportional to **v^2**, as I elaborated in my eqn. 3) above. Your **p**, I assume, equals to **p = 0.5*rho*Cd*A**.

Comment: p is a constant - NOT a variable the way I am using it. I assure you again that dv/dt=g-p*v

Comment: If the 3 terms I used are constant (assuming rho does not change), then p is indeed constant. I don't have a problem with **p**. My problem is with **v**. I believe that you are assuring me a wrong equation. Can you link to a reference for your equation?

Comment: @Joe - thanks for providing a link. Note that according the reference document, eqn. (2) refers only to *spherical, small* object, and the author uses the term "reasonable to assume" (honestly, I don't know why it is *reasonable* to assume that). In reality, it is more a function of the Rayleigh number than the shape. Now, the actual drag is a combination of a few drag contributions. In high speeds (such as the case with the bullet), the dominant contributor is the Newtonian drag, which is a function of **v^2**.

Comment: In the last comment, "Rayleigh" should have been "Reynolds number".

Comment: @ysap It was a pleasure working with you.

Comment: @Joe: Physics.SE has the MathJax latex interpreter running. This is tool that renders the spiffy equations you will see in other peoples posts. I'd heartily recommend that you try it out.